# When switching fragments, does fragments go onPause()?

Tags: android

Hello everyone i have a simple question:
(In Sliding menu) when we switch between fragments, does fragments go onPause?? or what?
Thanks

Also tried that:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    Log.d("onpause", "sorna bel on pause");
}
```

logcat shows nothing.

Comment: To find out stuff like this => Set a breakpoint in the fragment's `onPause()` method, then start your app with debugging. Thereafter trigger the sliding menu and see if your breakpoint is triggered. Simpler than waiting for a response here on SO.

Comment: If it doesn't show anything then the method isn't called.

Answer (score 0):

yes...the onPause() method will be called, when you switch to another fragment. In the future please test it by your self. Implement the onPause() and put a Toast or a Log.d into it.

Comment: Yeap did it! I got no toast. i even tried System.out.println("going on pause"); and the logcat showed nothing.

Comment: You will have to Log it to see it in logcat aka Log.d("TAG", "going on pause");

Comment: Hmm...strange. If it's important for you, please post more code.

Comment: I think they go 'onDestroy()'. You might want to try that.